# jQuery Sortable Lists, Save Order to MySQL

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I'm trying to implement dragable sorting and saving the order to mysql using php and jQuery.
Here's the scenario.
Say, I have 3 items listed as Messages, Disputes and Services.

- Messages: 
   msg1 
   msg2  
   msg3...
- Disputes:  
   disp1  
   disp2  
   disp3...
- Services:  
   ser1  
   ser2  
   ser3...

the information shown above is coming from 3 different tables in mysql database.

I need drag and drop to sort the three sections Messages, Disputes and Services. Also I need to save the sorted order in the database.So the next time the page shows the sections with the saved sort order. Can anyone help me in this?

I have gone through many examples that saves the sorted order, but these examples are saving the static data in to database along with sort order.

[Dynamic Drag’n Drop With jQuery And PHP](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/dynamic-dragn-drop-with-jquery-and-php/)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to store it in a database? Would storing it client-side in a cookie be ok as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what drag-and-drop you will be using, but you will want to add an event when an item is dropped. Something like:

```
...,
drop: function() {
    string order = GetorderofElementsinContainer("ContainerID");
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "whatmethodtocall",
        data: "order=" + order,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Yippee, the order is saved!");
        }
    });
},
...
```

This will automatically trigger an update whenever you change the order. You'll have to check how to get the order and how to store it, but as I have no info on that, I can't help you there ;)

Comment: Hi Flater... thanks for your response... I have followed something similar to your suggestion and its working fine now. Thanks a lot for your suggestion

Comment: Happy to give back to the comunity that has helped me countless times ;)